# CloudFormation - How to start a Windows Service with cfn-init

Tags: windows-service, amazon-cloudformation

I'm creating a CloudFormation Stack that will install and start a service on a Windows Instance.  I've figured out how to install the service, but how do I start the service using cfn-init?

The [examples](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-init.html#aws-resource-init-services) seem to all use linux, as there is a reference to "sysvinit"  How do I structure AWS::CloudFormation::Init so that cfn-init will start windows services after installing them?  Do I leave in the sysvinit, replace it with something else, take it out?

ps:
I'm referring to how to start services by providing information to AWS::CloudFormation::Init.services.  Also, It would be nice to know how "packages" work for windows.  [AWS's announcemnet](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=1436) says that packages are supported on Windows but there is no Windows specific documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the following [response](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=398166#398222) to my respective post on the AWS CloudFormation Forum:

> Posted by:   Adam@AWS Posted on: Nov 7, 2012 9:05 AM  in response to:
>   Edwin G. Landy        Reply   Helpful Edwin,
>
> You can install an MSI package in much the same way as a yum package.
>   For instance:
>
> ```js
> "packages" : {
>    "msi" : { 
>       "mysql" : "URL or path to file on disk",
>       "package2" : "path to another MSI"
>    }
> }
> ```
>
> Note that the names do not matter - cfn-init will extract the
>   ProductCode from the MSI in order to determine if the package is
>   already installed or not. MSIs are also installed for all users with
>   reboots suppressed.
>
> I'm afraid we do not actually support services on Windows yet, but it
>   is a feature that is definitely on our roadmap. Until then you can use
>   the "net" command from within the command section to start services
>   from cfn-init.
>
> Thanks, Adam